# Login register 308

Tags: java, android, request, gson, android-volley

I have a web app + database hosted in python which I have tested and works for creating, logging in and logging out user. Now I'm trying to make the requests in my android application written in java. However, I keep getting 308 error.

Here is my RegisterActivity.java

```
private void register() {
    // Get headers, method and url to be used in the request
    final String user = username.getText().toString();
    final String pass = password.getText().toString();
    Map<String, String> userObject = new HashMap<>();
    userObject.put("username", user);
    userObject.put("password", pass);
    final int method = Request.Method.POST;
    final String url = "https://tddd80-app-joneri.azurewebsites.net/user";

    // Create request
    GsonRequest request = new GsonRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, userObject,
            response    -> System.out.println("Success! Response: " + response),
            error       -> System.out.println("Error with request: " + error.getMessage());

    // Add the request to the Volley request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(request);
```

and this is the most important part of GsonRequest which should parse JSON into string:

```
public class GsonRequest extends Request<String> {
    private final Map<String, String> headers;
    private final Response.Listener<String> listener;

    public GsonRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> headers,
                         Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener 
    errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.headers = headers;
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

The error:

```
E/Volley: [16210] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 308 
for https://tddd80-app-joneri.azurewebsites.net/user
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 308 is not an error in that sense, it indicates a [permanent redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/308).

Most likely when you manually tested your web server you used a tool which automatically follows HTTP redirects. For Volley it looks like it should follow redirects, except when the protocol changes between HTTP and HTTPS, see also this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/volley/issues/51).

Since the URL you are using already has `https://` maybe your web server redirects to a `http://` URL? In that case you should adjust your web server though because posting credentials over unencrypted HTTP should be avoided for security reasons.

Or you could also check the value of [`HttpURLConnection.getFollowRedirects()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection#getFollowRedirects()), maybe for some reason that is `false`.